# Finding a JQuery Accordion within 2 Divs

Tags: jquery

I had this question before but I may not have asked it correctly the first time, so here is my second attempt.  I am creating a site with dynamic web pages.  On one of these pages I have 3 accordions underneath a table, but surrounded in a Div called "wrapping".  In order to have these accordions seen as part of the dynamic page, I am including them within a Div I called "content" (as both ID name and class name for testing purposes).

Here is the HTML section for the dynamic content containing these accordions:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div id="content" class="content">
    <table style="width: 1200px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 800px">
                <h1>Title</h1><br />
                blah blah
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="wrapping" class="wrapping">
        <p class="accordionButton"><strong>Service 1</strong></p>
        <div class="accordionContent">  
            Item1<br />
            Item2<br/>
        </div>
        <p class="accordionButton"><strong>Service 2</strong></p>
        <div class="accordionContent">
            Item1<br />
            Item2<br />
        </div>
        <p class="accordionButton"><strong>Service 3</strong></p>
        <div class="accordionContent">
            Item1<br />
        </div>                       
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here is the entire relevant Jquery code segment I'm using:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.wrapping').find('p.accordionButton').each(function() 
       { alert("found it") });  //Test

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION    
    $('.wrapping').find('p.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    $(".accordionContent").hide();
    });
```

Here is the CSS associated with the program, including some styles that do not apply for this example:

```
  #load {   
     display: none;   
     position: absolute;   
     right: 10px;   
     top: 10px;   
     background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);   
     width: 43px;   
     height: 11px;   
     text-indent: -9999em;   
 }

 #nav-menu ul
 {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }

 #nav-menu li
 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.15em;
 }

 #nav-menu li a
 {
    background: url(background.gif) #fff bottom left repeat-x;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    float: left;
    width: 9em;
    display: block;
    border: 0.1em solid #dcdce9;
    color: #0d2474;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
 }

  #nav-menu li a
 {
   float: none
 }

 #nav-menu
 {
   width:30em
 } 

.accordionButton
{
width: 650px;
float: left;
background: #99CC99;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
 }

 .accordionContent {    
width: 650px;
float: left;
background: #95B1CE;
display: none;
}
```

Question:
I can find each of the accordion buttons on the page by the test statement above (I get 3 alerts, one for each accordionButton), but can't do a mouseover using the same method.  Why is that?

Comment: It works on [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff5Lf/). It has some logic errors, but the mouseover works.

Comment: @robert , its working for me also...from the cambraca provided link

Comment: The only way I can get the mouseover to work for me is if I move the whole "wrapping" div OUT OF the "content" div, so that one div follows the other instead of one being inside the other.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: do you have any CSS loaded? If so remove it and test again. Something 'could' be blocking the mouseover

Comment: @Robert: that sounds like a stacking order issue, is there any CSS that applies to `#content`,`#form1`, `#wrapping` or any other parent elements that youre not showing? specifically anything that involves the `position` and related css properties?

Comment: I have a CSS file that contains details on the properties of the AccordionButton and the AccordionContent.  When a disable the @import url(css.css) line in the Heading, I just get lists instead of Accordions.

Comment: @Robert I would try opening the file in firefox and use the firebug extension to see what is up. I can only think this is a stacking issue and that there is something in the way of your cursor and the element. It won't be the way you are calling jQuery because your alerts work. Do you have an empty <head> element? I would strip out everything not essential (like the table, jQueryUI) and test with that. Otherwise can you please copy the entire HTML of the page and paste it into jsbin or jsfiddle - hopefully it won't work there either and we can keep fiddling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the code that enabled dynamic pages. That simplified the code and removed a level of complexity.

The code shown above works, and I even made it fancier. If you are curious about it, check out my [test site](http://test.strictlyrestoration.com/welcome.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186412/jquery-accordion-buried-in-a-table-within-dynamic-page) and there is information there that is not in this post. It looks like you are using jQuery's `.load()` function to populate `<div id="content" />`. If you are then you need to use a live binding rather than a standard bind function.

`.mouseover(function())` is short hand for `.bind(mouseover,function())` and this will not work with content loaded after the DOM is initially generated. Instead you should use `.live(mouseover,function())` which will included any content added to the DOM by a `.load()` function. Here is more information on live binding: [jQuery's .live() handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

In addition to this you should (as mentioned by others) use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` because the latter will fire when you hover over any element with the one you specify, whereas the latter only fires once per element or children. I have explained it badly - here is a link for better information and an interactive example: [jQuery's mouseenter event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: You've given me a lot to think about here.  Since I'm a newbie with this, it may take a few days to process this and try it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

mouseover can be very quirky it is advised to use mouseenter

Comment: How is mouseover quirky? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @cambraca , sometimes even i experienced some flickering on menus in IE

Comment: mouseover bubbles up so if your moving you mouse to that internal div you could be  triggering your function twice.

and if you move back out it can be triggered a third time

Comment: The same issue applies if I change this to a MouseClick, so it may be the way I'm calling the Jquery.min.js files.  The only thing I can come up with so far.

Comment: did you try alerting to see if you function is firing?

Comment: The "find each" test I set up with the alert definitely fires (first Jquery line).  Its the mouseover function right under it that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking, but you can surely use a little tweak to your mouseover function.

```
$('.wrapping').find('p.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')){
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    }
});
```

This will improve the accordion usability, e.g. only switching view pane when intended.

Or.. perhaps try this modification:

```
$('.wrapping').find('p.accordionButton').each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    });
});
```

Comment: Obviously something is wrong with my setup because this does nothing for me either.  I'm currently using the following:         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
Am I missing something here??

Comment: Does this link work for you? http://impossible2possible.com/so/4287077.php ... jquery 1.4.3 used to run your script

Comment: That second modification works beautifully - only if I move the inner DIV out of the outer DIV, making them sequential.  (scratching head)

Comment: What browser/version are you using? Also, css rules may be playing tricks on you. If you are using any CSS during testing, please provide your styling rules.

Comment: I'm using VS2005 SP1 with IE7.  I will add my CSS code above right now.

Comment: Dumb question: are you testing using http://locahost or file://  ... your js scripts might not work unless your testing using your webserer (e.g. Apache).

Comment: Also, what is the reason for the "float:left" value for .accordionButton and .accordionContent? The accordion displays broken with those values set, but displays nicely when removing the float values.

Comment: I'm testing using localhost.  Again, the scripts DO work but only if I rearrange my HTML, but I need the DIV within the DIV as shown.

Comment: When adding alert($(this).text()); to the mouseover handler, does it alert the button's text when you hover over a button? E.g. hovering over Service 3 should alert "Service 3". Your problem is very weird :) seems to work fine on my IE7.

Comment: It's possible that I'm calling the remote Jquery.min.js files incorrectly or incompletely.  How do you have yours set up?  I'm still a newbie at this.

Comment: <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 google.load('jquery', '1.4.3');
 google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.2");
 /* ]]> */
</script>

Comment: That is definitely not the way I have it.  Why is the CDATA section commented out?  Should I include that?

Comment: It's so that "Javascript code is handled correctly both by newer browsers and validators that actually understand the XHTML DTD as well as by older web browsers that don't understand XHTML and interpret everything on the page as HTML" http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm